# htaccess redirect URL with parameter when a special parameter exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope to get help for the following task:

I want to redirect a domain with `.htaccess` only when `index.php` is called and when a special parameter is given.
Let's say I have the following URL

`https://www.my-domain.com/index.php?action=status-check&licence=80586f63&product=RFDE&domain=domain.tld`

When this URL is called and the parameter `action` exists it should be redirected to

`https://www.other-domain.com/index.php?action=status-check&licence=80586f63&product=RFDE&domain=domain.tld`

If just

`https://www.my-domain.com/index.php?parm=4711`

or

`https://www.my-domain.com/index.php`

is called or any other URL with in this domain but without the parameter `action`, nothing should happen.

Can somebody help me to find the right condition and rule?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)my-domain\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.other-domain.com/$0 [R=302,L]
```

This redirects `www.my-domain.com/index.php` (with or without the www subdomain) when the `action` URL parameter exists anywhere in the query string (although your example only shows this at the *start* of the query string?). The URL-path and query string are both preserved in the redirect to `www.other-domain.com`. The `action` URL parameter could have any value.

The `$0` backreference contains the entire match of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `index.php` on success. The original query string is passed through by default - there is nothing extra you need to do here in order to redirect to the *same* query string.

If `www.other-domain.com` is on a different server and no other domains could conflict at the originating host then you could perhaps remove the first condition that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable.

Comment: You are awesome @MrWhite. This is exactely what I was looking for. I didn't know the $0 parameter, which solves my problem. Thank you very much for taking the time and answering my question!