# htaccess redirect with query string not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

`enter code here`I have a WordPress website.

I have URLs for affiliates that look like this:

```
https://example.com/folder/?ref=23432
https://example.com/folder/?ref=13442
etc.
```

I would like to redirect any URL that ends in `?ref=` to another domain.

For example, `https://example.com/folder/?ref=` should redirect to `https://example.org/product/`

How can I do this?  I appreciate your time.

I tried

```
Redirect 301 example.com/folder/?ref   https://example.org/product/
```

Thank you @MrWhite.  I tried the following with no success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ref=
RewriteRule ^example.com https://www.example.org/product/$0 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: As per [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), the mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only (not the hostname or the query string). You need to use mod_rewrite, as per the linked "duplicate" question. If you are still having problems then update your question showing your revised attempt and precisely what is not working.

Comment: Does `example.com` and `example.org` point to the same place?

Comment: No.  They are on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^example.com https://www.example.org/product/$0 [R=302,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive matches the URL-path only (less the slash prefix). So this should be matching against `folder/` (as per your example), not the hostname.

And the `$0` backreference in the *substitution* string is not required here. So this should simply be:

```
:
RewriteRule ^folder/$ https://www.example.org/product/ [R=302,L]
```

If you do need to check the requested hostname (ie. `example.com`) - if `example.com` and `example.org` point to the same server - then you need a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive). For example, the complete rule would then become:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ref=
RewriteRule ^folder/$ https://www.example.org/product/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that the regex `(^|&)ref=` matches the `ref=` URL parameter *anywhere* in the query string, if there happened to be other URL parameters that preceded it.

Reference:

- [htaccess redirect URL with parameter when a special parameter exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258484/htaccess-redirect-url-with-parameter-when-a-special-parameter-exists)
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule